# Kubernetes: get real client source IP of incoming packet

Tags: iptables, kubernetes, coreos

I want to get the actual IP using which the client sent out the packet in my app sitting in a kubernetes pod.

I did some searches and [found](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3760) that this was not supported earlier but supported later.

I ungraded my setup and here is the current setup version:

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"1", GitVersion:"v1.1.3", GitCommit:"6a81b50c7e97bbe0ade075de55ab4fa34f049dc2", GitTreeState:"clean"}

$ kubectl api-versions
extensions/v1beta1
v1
```

I also ran:

```
$ for node in $(kubectl get nodes -o name); do kubectl annotate $node net.beta.kubernetes.io/proxy-mode=iptables; done
```

This now gives:

> error: --overwrite is false but found the following declared
>   annotation(s): 'net.beta.kubernetes.io/proxy-mode' already has a value
>   (iptables)
>
> error: --overwrite is false but found the following declared
>   annotation(s): 'net.beta.kubernetes.io/proxy-mode' already has a value
>   (iptables)

I also rebooted all the boxes.

However, I still get IP of docker0 interface of the worker node when the packet is received inside my application.

[Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3760), I read:

> But that will not expose external client IPs, just intra cluster IPs.

So, the question is how to get the real, external client IP when I get a packet.

The packets are not http/websocket packets, but plain TCP packets if this is relevant to get an answer.

I also tried following this [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/3760#issuecomment-150747217) but did not get lucky. App continued to get packets with `docker0` interface IP as source IP. May be I could not copy-paste the stuff. I don't know how to get `kube-proxy` IP and just used worker machine IP there. I am just getting started with Kubernetes and CoreOS.